# Using method imported python module without explicitly calling import

Tags: python, pip, python-import, colorama

I have some code where I want to use colorama terminal colouring but to do so (since this code will run on different machines), I need to make sure the colorama module exists on the current pc and if not, install it from within the code and then import it.

Currently I have this:

```
def import_or_install(package, version):
    try:
        __import__(package)
    except ImportError:
        subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '{}=={}'.format(package, version)])
```

In my case, package is "colorama" and version is "0.4.1" but when I run the following, I get an error saying "name 'colorama' is not defined" and I don't know how to use colorama after installing it via import_or_install.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import_or_install("colorama", "0.4.1")

    colorama.init()
    print(colorama.Fore.RED, 'some red text')
    print(colorama.Back.GREEN, 'and with a green background')
    print(colorama.Style.DIM, 'and in dim text')
    print(colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
    print('back to normal now')
```

I would greatly appreciate an explanation on how I can make this work (maybe use a second python code to do the install and then run the main code ?)

Comment: When and where does the `name 'colorama' is not defined` error occur? Can you tell if the installing via `subprocess` is working?

Comment: at colorama.init()

Comment: Why not just calling `import pip; pip.main(['install', package])` before import? You can even make sure the right version is installed.

Comment: pip.main doesn't work anymore, I'd need to revert back to version 9.x or something which I don't really want to do on every machine this will run on

Comment: You may have to make `import_or_install()` return the result of calling `__import__(package)`. This means you'll need to attempt to do it again after the `subprocess.call()` returns. After doing that you could use `colorama = import_or_install("colorama", "0.4.1")`.

Comment: My mistake, try: `from pip._internal import main`

Comment: I mixed a bit of everything and it works now :D Thanks